# Socket use in python

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, python-sockets

I want to create a chat program between two machines. I am using machine *one* which has the IP address 192.168.0.5, I can successfully send a message to machine *two* 192.168.0.2, and then send a message in response from machine two, to machine 1.

However I encountered a problem on the second send attempt from either machine, (noticing that before sending the second time I wait for a response from the initial send) claiming that the IP address is already in use or connection is refused, how can this be changed so that a defined number of choices can be sent?

I appreciate that the following code is not the most efficient way of sending and receiving multiple messages, that would be some description of for loop. For example `for sendAndRecieve in range(0,5)`.

The two machines are linked using ethernet cables running through a switch and the code is run simultaneously.

Machine 1 code:

```
#Sending first message

host = "192.168.0.5"
port = 4446
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print("listening")
q,addr = s.accept(1024)
data = "This is the first message I am sending"
data = data.encode("utf-8")
q.send(data)
s.close

#Recieving response message 1

while True:
    try:
        host = "192.168.0.2"
        port = 4446
        from socket import*
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host,port))
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        msg = msg.decode("utf-8")
        print(msg)
        s.close()
    except:
        pass

#Sending second message this is where the problem happens

host = "192.168.0.5"
port = 4446
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print("listening")
q,addr = s.accept(1024)
data = "This is the first message I am sending"
data = data.encode("utf-8")
q.send(data)
s.close
```

Machine 2 code:

```
#Recieving message 1

while True:
    try:
        host = "192.168.0.5"
        port = 4446
        from socket import*
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host,port))
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        msg = msg.decode("utf-8")
        print(msg)
        s.close()
    except:
        pass

#Sending first message

host = "192.168.0.2"
port = 4446
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print("listening")
q,addr = s.accept(1024)
data = "This is the first message I am sending"
data = data.encode("utf-8")
q.send(data)
s.close

#Recieving response message 1 this is where the problem happens

while True:
    try:
        host = "192.168.0.25"
        port = 4446
        from socket import*
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host,port))
        msg = s.recv(1024)
        msg = msg.decode("utf-8")
        print(msg)
        s.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your code, I don't see how Machine 2's while loop will ever stop trying to receive data from Machine 1 (there's no break in the loop other than if an error is encountered). Machine 1 does continue on after Machine 2 connects the first time, but then tries to connect to Machine 2 while Machine 2 is trying to connect to Machine 1. That's probably the cause of the error that you're seeing, and why you only see the first message sent/received.